# Trying to create a % column on a Pandas Dataframe, but only getting NaN Values

Tags: python, pandas

I´m trying to add a percentage column into a dataframe, but when i try to add it to the new column all i get is NaN values

To create the column 'percent_clicked' on the 'clicks_pivot' df:

```
clicks_pivot['percent_clicked'] = (clicks_pivot.user_id / clicks_pivot.user_id.sum()) * 100
```

Printing the modified 'clicks_pivot' i get:

utm_source

email   255 NaN

facebook504 NaN

google  680 NaN

twitter 215 NaN

How can i get the % instead of the NaN values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it works, i tested. Before using the code make sure the column in question is not holding strings instead of ints.

```
df['b'] = (df['a'] / df['a'].sum()) * 100
```

Comment: Yeah! It Does, i had an error before when i created the df!